# Twisted: How do I destroy a connection?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I keep a list of client connections which are setup like this:

```
cons = {}
sid = 5
cons[sid] = self.reactor.connectTCP(host, port, myprotocol)
```

If the item is still connected, and I call `del cons[5]` , the connection object still persists.  I can see the output in my server console. The object is definitely gone from the dict though.

I can call .disconnect() on it, and then call `del cons[5]` , and it does disconnect and remove the item, but I'm concerned that the connection still exists somewhere.

What would be the proper way to destroy one of these connections?

Comment: Here's a pretty good explanation: http://blackjml.livejournal.com/23029.html